# Using Newton's binomial theorem to prove that a sum evaluates to $36^n-26^n$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

Using Newton's binomial theorem to argue that: $n \ge 1$
$$36^n - 26^n = \sum_{k=1}^{n}\binom{n}{k}10^k \cdot 26^{n-k}$$
                              my argument
$$(26+10)^n = \sum_{k=1}^{n}\binom{n}{k}10^k \cdot 26^{n-k} +26^n $$
$$(26+10)^n = \sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}10^k \cdot 26^{n-k} +26^n $$

I'm stuck at the part on what to do with the $26^n$ After I moved it over a made the sum $\sum_{k=1}^{n}$ to $\sum_{k=1}^{n}$

Comment: @CareBear I also rolled back the destructive edit on [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/948779/prove-this-equality-by-using-newtons-binomial-theorem), of which it is also a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

We first take the binomial expansion of $(26+10)^n$.
$$
\begin{align}
(26+10)^n&=\sum_{k=0}^n10^k\cdot26^{n-k}\\
&=26^n+\sum_{k=1}^n10^k\cdot26^{n-k}
\end{align}
$$
Notice that we pulled out $26^n$ from our sum.

Therefore, by subtracting $26^n$ from both sides we obtain
$$\begin{align}
(26+10)^n-26^n&=\sum_{k=1}^n10^k\cdot26^{n-k}\\
36^n-26^n&=
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Hi, Why would I be moving the 26^n to the LHS when I moved it to the RHS in my first step? Is it to move it back after you've made k=0? I don't really understand

Comment: I'll do a step by step argument to clarify things.

Answer (score 2):

$$
\sum_{k=0}^n \binom n k 10^k \cdot 26^{n-k} = \underbrace{\sum_{k=0}^n \binom n k a^k b^{n-k} = (a+b)^n}_{\text{This is what the theorem says.}} = (10 + 26)^n = 36^n.
$$

(You wanted to prove $$36^n-26^n = \sum_{k=1}^n\binom n k 10^k\cdot26^{n-k},$$ with the sum starting at $1$ rather than at $0$.  If you add $26^n$ to both sides, you have $$36^n = 26^n + \sum_{k=1}^n\binom n k 10^k\cdot26^{n-k},$$ and that is the same as $$\binom n 0 10^0\cdot 26^{n-0} + \sum_{k=1}^n\binom n k 10^k\cdot26^{n-k} = \sum_{k=0}^n\binom n k 10^k\cdot26^{n-k},$$ with the sum starting at $0$, not at $1$, because the term $26^n$ is $\binom n 0 10^0\cdot 26^{n-0}$.)

Comment: hi, but the sum did not start at k=0 so, I moved 26^n to the RHS. Would that make it start at k=0?

Comment: You wanted to prove $36^n-26^n = \sum_{k=1}^n\binom n k 10^k\cdot26^{n-k}$, with the sum starting at $1$ rather than at $0$.  If you add $26^n$ to both sides, you have $36^n = 26^n + \sum_{k=1}^n\binom n k 10^k\cdot26^{n-k}$, and that is the same as $\sum_{k=0}^n\binom n k 10^k\cdot26^{n-k}$, with the sum starting at $0$, not at $1$, because the term $26^n$ is $\binom n 0 10^0\cdot 26^{n-0}$. ${}\qquad{}$